# What does the $d$ mean in metric tensor calculations?

Tags: metric-tensor, differentiation, notation, calculus

In many metric calculations, like the Schwartzschild metric, we see formulas like $d^2X / dt^2$ and many other formulas with a $d$ in them.  You'd be surprised that I've been looking for months to find just what does the $d$ means. It is just not written anywhere.  I finally found that it stands for derivative, but they don't give me any more than that.  I can understand the concept of $dt^2$ meaning the derivative of $t$ is squared.  But how do I interpret $d^2x $?  What is being squared, just "derivative"?  What does the concept of derivative mean in general when looking at metric tensors?

Comment: I think $d^n x$ just means the volume element in an $n$ dimensional space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $d$ is part of [Leibniz’s notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_notation) for [differential calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus).

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ is a second [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative)... the time derivative of the time derivative of $x(t)$.

In a formula like

$$ds^2=c^2 dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2,$$

$ds$, $dt$, etc. are [differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function), which physicists tend to think of as infinitesimal changes or differences.

You will need to learn differential calculus as a first step toward understanding General Relativity.

Comment: Looking at this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative at the diagram on the right.  The red line is the derivative of the black line at one particular point. Would the "second derivative' be a derivative of a collection of all the red lines drawn along the black line?

Comment: The red line is not the derivative. The derivative at that point is the *slope* of that line, which is just a *number*. So the derivative of a function is another function. The first derivative measures how fast a function changes. The second derivative measures how fast the first derivative changes. Etc. I’m sorry, but I cannot teach you more differential calculus in comments. And calculus is math, not physics.

Comment: I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8xtjVGnnXo which explains it clearly. Thanks for your help.